# Why is Raven generating an already existing document Id for my new document?

Tags: c#, ravendb

Why does this code (attempt to) overwrite my first object with the second? My first object specifically has an Id of "StringBasedIdClasses/1", and the second one does not provide an Id, so Raven should generate an unused Id shouldn't it?

```
 var quickStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore() { RunInMemory = true };
 quickStore.Initialize();
 quickStore.RegisterListener(new DocumentConversionListener()).RegisterListener(new DocumentStoreListener());

 using (var session = quickStore.OpenSession())
 {
      session.Advanced.UseOptimisticConcurrency = true;
      var stringIdTest = new StringBasedIdClass()
      {
           Id = "StringBasedIdClasses/1",
           Name = "StringItem1"
      };

      session.Store(stringIdTest);
      session.SaveChanges();
 }

 using (var session = quickStore.OpenSession())
 {
      session.Advanced.UseOptimisticConcurrency = true;
      var stringIdTest = new StringBasedIdClass()
      {
           Name = "DidIReplaceYou"
      };

      session.Store(stringIdTest);
      session.SaveChanges();//This fails with a ConcurrencyViolation as I use OptimisticConcurrency and have Etag support on my objects
 }
```

Everything is using one current instance of a document store. This seems pretty basic so must have missed something simple.

Comment: You didn't let RavenDB generate the Id on the first one. Looks like it's working as intended.

Comment: No...that's my point. I have to bulk import some items from a previous sytem, that already have Ids that we need to use. This is a simplified version of that code when the issues were detected

Regardless of whether I give the Id or Raven generates it - it should be aware of an Id that already exists! There is no way that is "working as intended".

Comment: You're specifying the Id, that's working as intended. Just manually update the HiLo after the import is done.

Comment: You can also use `session.Store(stringIdText, "StringBasedIdClasses/<InsertIdHere>")` replacing `<InsertIdHere>` with the Id you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HiLo key generator of RavenDB doesn't know that `StringBasedIdClasses/1` is already in use, therefore it assigns it to your second document. See [Document IDs generation strategies](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/basic-operations/saving-new-document#document-ids-generation-strategies) for details.

Comment: Naturally I have already read the documentation on this. So are these strategies incompatible then? Because I'm aware of the different ways to create an id, but I have never seen a comment that implies they can't all be used together. For example in SQL server, t import a load of data with specific Ids I would use an IDENTITY INSERT , which I would turn off after the import. How do I seed a raven store with data with known ids, before allowing the default strategy to continue?

Answer (score 7):

Ok, the answer is in part what Thomas said, but more specifically RavenDb completely ignores Ids you insert manually. In order to do a bulk import (say a data migration from old system to new system like I am doing you need to do the following:

1. Ensure that any document stores connecting to that database are disposed of (normally this means, don't have your application running
2. Bulk import into the system, setting the ids yourself (you are responsible for ensuring you don't overwrite any existing records, but you can use optimistic concurrency and etags for this)
3. At the end of the import, set the hilo (basically the starting point for new ids) for your collection to a value higher than the highest id now in the system using the following code:

   ```
   session.Store(new {Id = "Raven/Hilo/{yourcollectionname}", Max = newMaxValue});
   session.SaveChanges();
   ```
4. *Now* when you initialize a new store the correct hilo values will be used.

Note that this process is impossible to emulate with the In-Memory version of `EmbeddableDocumentStore` as you essentially create a brand new server instance every time you open a store. So if you are trying to do integration tests assuming known ids of existing/non existing records, you will have to let Raven select the ids and not set them in your own objects. This should work fine as your new in memory store will always start from 1 anyway. To ensure the isolation of my tests, I opened a new store for every test.